# Android alpha animation fadein fadeout with delays

Tags: android, animation, alpha, fadein, fadeout

I want to do a very simple alpha animation but I cannot find a valid way.

The idea is to perform this animation over a view:

1. alpha from 0 to 1 of 1 second
2. hold alpha at 1 for 5 seconds
3. alpha from 1 to 0 of 1 second
4. hold alpha at 0 for 5 seconds.
5. start again on 1.

I've tried to implement that with an AnimationSet as:

```
AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation animation1 = new AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
animation1.setDuration(1000);

Animation animation2 = new AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
animation2.setDuration(1000);
animation2.setStartOffset(5000);

Animation animation3 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f);
animation3.setDuration(4000)
animation3.setStartOffset(6000);

animationSet.add(animation1);
animationSet.add(animation2);
animationSet.add(animation3);
```

etc..

but it seams that the third animation do a mess with all the alpha animations, I supose that this cause an internal incoherence in the way that Android manage this type of animation.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell me if my code worked well ? And please accept the answer if yes

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Ok Keep in mind these 2 points to solve this

---

- If I want to animate `1.0f to 0.0f` after 5 seconds with an animation duration of 1 seconds, this is ultimately a 1 second animation with a pause of 5 seconds.

  To acheive this:

  1. `setDuration(1000)` (it has a 1 second duration)
  2. `setStartOffset(5000)` (it will start after 5 seconds)

---

- You only need 2 animations that will loop forever.

  1.`0.0f to 1.0f` with 5 seconds pause and 1 second duration

  2.`1.0f to 0.0f` with 5 seconds pause and 1 second duration

---

And here is the code:

```
    animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation1.setDuration(1000);
    animation1.setStartOffset(5000);

    animation2 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    animation2.setDuration(1000);
    animation2.setStartOffset(5000);

    textView.startAnimation(animation1);
```

However to loop forever I will use `AnimationListener` because repeatCount is buggy:

```
    animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation1.setDuration(1000);
    animation1.setStartOffset(5000);

    //animation1 AnimationListener
    animation1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            // start animation2 when animation1 ends (continue)
            textView.startAnimation(animation2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    animation2 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    animation2.setDuration(1000);
    animation2.setStartOffset(5000);

    //animation2 AnimationListener
    animation2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            // start animation1 when animation2 ends (repeat)
            textView.startAnimation(animation1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    textView.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: well can it use to wait 5 second and then show something? in order to handler.post delay.

Answer (score 20):

There is a simpler solution to this.

Lets assume that your view is in state GONE. To animate to its visibility:

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
yourView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(300);
```

Through the same way you can add animation listeners.

This also works for scale and translation animations.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
val shortAnimationDuration = 1000
            yourView.apply {
                alpha = 0f
                animate()
                    .alpha(1f)
                    .setDuration(shortAnimationDuration.toLong())
                    .setListener(object :AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
                        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                           //You can add what you want to do after completing animation
                        }
                    })
            }
```

This is a **Fade in** animation. If you want Fade out you just swap the alpha values.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, I am using the animation inside a util function for any generic View and I was able to achieved this by defining the values inline this way:

```
fun View.fadeIn(durationMillis: Long = 250, delay: Long = 1000) {
    this.startAnimation(AlphaAnimation(0F, 1F).apply {
        duration = durationMillis
        startOffset = delay
        fillAfter = true
    })
}
```