# Animating/transitioning text/textViews - android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, textview

Basically I have implemented a fade out function from one textView to another, and I'm wanting to know how I could fade out after delay or transition to other text after delay.

Java code:

```
 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            pView.setText("Nice");
            pView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PlayScreen.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
```

The code works fine in my app and
I've found other questions that use other ways for animations but nothing useful to this method, or would it be better to use the valueAnimator?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298330/android-alpha-animation-fadein-fadeout-with-delays) it may help.

Comment: @user7790438 thanks! this did help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations
You can use this library it's very simple